# data.table: feeding list of logical conditions in i

Tags: r, data.table, boolean-expression

I have to write a long script (call it Script) doing various operations on a data.table, then apply this a few times for different subsets of rows. I would like to be able to do the following:

```
condition <- "X>10"
source(Script)
```

... where Script will contain many of the following:

```
dt[MAGIC(condition), .......]
```

This would allow me to keep Script and the condition in different files (the second a markdown showing the results only, and which I'd like to be as simple as possible in terms of code).

What I don't want is to copy paste the script for each of the conditions, and manually change it, since this is way too error prone.

I tried lots of combinations of parse, deparse, substitute, quote, as.expression, as.logical, etc. but I seem to be staggering in the dark. I'd be really grateful if somebody could help!

NB: I can easily do the above in dplyr:

```
df %>% filter_(condition)
```

and of course I can also turn this back into a data.table

```
df %>% filter_(condition) %>% data.table()
```

... but I'd rather work consistently with data.table (faster, prefer the syntax, etc.)

Comment: You can use `dt[eval(parse(text=condition))]`

Comment: Thank you @akrun !!

Comment: Or write your condition like `cond = quote(X>10)` and do `DT[eval(cond)]` -- this is actually simpler in terms of code, since the condition is being stored as a valid language object and less code is required to evaluate it. `quote` will also conveniently fail if passed unparseable stuff, like `quote(x ^^ :)` unlike `"x ^^ :"`. Also, minor note: `filter_` is being phased out for some other syntax... if you want a chain, there's `DT %>% \`[\`(i = eval(e))`, which I sometimes do with magrittr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `eval(parse`

```
setdT(dt)[eval(parse(text=condition))]
```